# Regex - Python - exclude new line from match

Tags: python, regex

Why the following regex matches the specified string even though the end character is new line character? And how to exclude such string from being matched ?

```
import re

match = re.match(r"^\d{4}$", "1234\n")
print(match != None)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```py
\A\d+\Z
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IfXQq1/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\A`: `\A` asserts position at start of the string
- `\Z` asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)